# Solving a system of equations with boolean variables in $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I have a problem that reduces to a system of $2n+1$ equalities on $4n$ variables all in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, where the variables are constrained to be in $\{0,1\}$, *i.e.*,

$$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k \equiv a\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$$

$$x_2 + x_3 + ... + x_l \equiv b\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$$

$$\cdots$$

$$x_m + ... + x_{4n} \equiv c\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$$

The right hand side ($a$, $b$, $c$, $\ldots$) is known, but not necessarily in $\{0,1\}$ but in $\{0,1,2\}$.

I have found no better way of solving this
but a brute-force approach on the free variables, because doing Gaussian elimination, I can get a an upper triangular system, but that would only give me a solution if my variables were in $\{0,1,2\}$.

So my question is whether there is a more efficient, polynomial-time, way to solve this system that I may have missed? If not is there a complexity result that shows this problem to be hard in the general case ?

Comment: After Gaussian elimination, can you look at the solutions and see if any solution only uses $0$ and $1$?

Comment: I thought about that but with 2n+1 equations for 4n variables there would be around $3^{2n}$ solutions no ? So going through all of them would be more costly than bruteforcing the variables.

Comment: If you wanted to "brute force" it, it would only be $2^{\#\text{free variables}}$ since those would be set to either $0$ or $1$ and you would immediately determine the pivot variables.  And, if you work backwards, you can likely cut that down dramatically.  Perhaps you could provide an example where $n=2$.

Comment: Yes you are right but my goal would be to solve this in polynomial time if it's possible.

Comment: Do you have 2n+1 inequalities or equation? Are the coefficients always 0/1? Are the LHS always a consecutive sequence of variables?

Comment: 2n+1 equalities sorry for the mistake. The coefficients are always 0/1, and the system has rank 2n+1. Every equation is a consecutive sequence of variables starting at the kth variable for the kth equation, but of different lengths.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but couldn't you reformulate it to an integer-programming problem, replacing the mod-3 thing with $\ldots = 3y_1 + a$ and adding constraints $0\leq x_i\leq 1$. I know that theoretically, integer programming is NP-hard, but maybe some software-package would just succeed to find the solution...

Comment: Does $k$ have some relation to $\ell$? Is $m$ equal to $2n+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find a solution to the system :

$$Ax = b$$

Where $A$ is a binary matrix, $x = (x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)^T$ a vector of variables, and $b = (b_1, b_2, ..., b_m)$ a vector of right-hand side, with $b_i \in \{0, 1, 2\} \; \forall i \in \{1, ..., m\}$.

### If so, you want to solve an Integer Program.

Unfortunately [integer programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) are NP-Complete in general, and your special case includes the [set-partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem, which is also NP-complete.

### How to solve it

Because integer programs have **a lot** of real-life applications, specialized algorithms and software have been devised to solve them. In my experience, solving a problem with fewer than 1000 variables should take less than a second, but it really depends on the problem... The solvers offering the highest performances are probably [cplex](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/cplex-optimizer) or [gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/) (they are not free, but I think they offer a free student version). There are also open source solvers such as [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) and [lp_solve](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/). If you have a relatively small problem (maybe less than 100 variables), you can even use the Excel solver, although it really not the best!

In any case, you **do not** want to code it yourself. Those software have *decades* of improvments into them and that is why they work well.

### How the algorithm works

Every commercial solver solves the problem by *[branch-and-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound)*.

> A branch-and-bound algorithm consists of a systematic enumeration of
> candidate solutions by means of state space search: the set of
> candidate solutions is thought of as forming a rooted tree with the
> full set at the root. The algorithm explores branches of this tree,
> which represent subsets of the solution set. Before enumerating the
> candidate solutions of a branch, the branch is checked against upper
> and lower estimated bounds on the optimal solution, and is discarded
> if it cannot produce a better solution than the best one found so far
> by the algorithm.

Your problem is a feasibility problem and not an optimization problem, so there is no need to compute bounds. However, the algorithm has to check wheather the current branch is infeasible. This is usually done by solving a linear relaxation of the problem (accepting solutions with fractional variables).

Commercial solvers also use many tricks to reduce to speed up the algorithm. Unfortunately, many of those tricks are secrets!